# Since spacetime can bend and form waves, does this mean it must be made of sub-units of matter? How can something bend if it does not have sub-units?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, space, loop-quantum-gravity

My question is philosophical, I'm just curious to hear people's opinions. I'm also interested in any resources that are related to this question. Have you read any papers that attempt to investigate this question or propose an answer?

LIGO has already proven that space itself can warp/change shape. To me, it's impossible for something to bend if it isn't made up of subunits. Lets say we had an object that was only made of one unit of matter, in other words, this object is not made up of smaller sub-units like atoms. It is just one unit of matter. Wouldn't this mean it's impossible to bend it?

In your opinion, is this question even up for debate? Has LIGO not only proven that space can form waves, but has also proved that space is made up of sub-units of matter? If not, why? Can you think of a way spacetime can bend without being made up of sub-units?

Answer (score 3):

When we say "spacetime is curved" in General Relativity, we mean that the [Riemann curvature tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) - which loosely tells you how a vector will change when [parallel-transported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) around a loop - is non-zero.  This implies that the [metric tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) is not the same as the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric) from special relativity, which has implications for the trajectories that freely-falling bodies will follow.

None of this requires modeling spacetime as somehow being constructed from matter.  Gravitational waves are disturbances in this curvature tensor field (or the metric tensor field) in more or less the same way as a sound wave is a disturbance in the air's pressure field (the former being far more complicated, of course).